# Python - program for searching for relevant cells in excel does not work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I've written a code to search for relevant cells in an excel file. However, it does not work as well as I had hoped.
In pseudocode, this is it what it should do:

```
Ask for input excel file
Ask for input textfile containing keywords to search for
Convert input textfile to list containing keywords
For each keyword in list, scan the excelfile
If the keyword is found within a cell, write it into a new excelfile
Repeat with next word
```

The code works, but some keywords are not found while they are present within the input excelfile. I think it might have something to do with the way I iterate over the list, since when I provide a single keyword to search for, it works correctly. This is my whole code: https://pastebin.com/euZzN3T3

This is the part I suspect is not working correctly. Splitting the textfile into a list works fine (I think).

```
#IF TEXTFILE
elif btext == True:
    #Split each line of textfile into a list
    file = open(txtfile, 'r')
    #Keywords in list
    for line in file:          
        keywordlist = file.read().splitlines()
    nkeywords = len(keywordlist)    
    print(keywordlist)
    print(nkeywords)

    #Iterate over each string in list, look for match in .xlsx file
    for i in range(1, nkeywords):
        nfound = 0
        ws_matches.cell(row = 1, column = i).value = str.lower(keywordlist[i-1])
        for j in range(1, worksheet.max_row + 1):
            cursor = worksheet.cell(row = j, column = c)
            cellcontent = str.lower(cursor.value)
            if match(keywordlist[i-1], cellcontent) == True:
                ws_matches.cell(row = 2 + nfound, column = i).value = cellcontent
                nfound = nfound + 1
```

and my `match()` function:

```
def match(keyword, content):
"""Check if the keyword is present within the cell content, return True if found, else False"""
if content.find(keyword) == -1:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

I'm new to Python so my apologies if the way I code looks like a warzone. Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong (or could be doing better?)? Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: I'm here to point you to the wonderful `in` operator :D https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators

Comment: Thanks!  This simplified my code and I immediately noticed that I only lowered the word in the list once to print out at the top of the column, and I forgot to do the same for the comparison. Now it works! Python is great!

Comment: Wait until you run into module pathing issues :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Splitting the textfile into a list works fine (I think).

This is something you should actually test (hint: it does but is inelegant). The best way to make easily testable code is to isolate functional units into separate functions, i.e. you could make a function that takes the name of a text file and returns a list of keywords. Then you can easily check if that bit of code works on its own. A more pythonic way to read lines from a file (which is what you do, assuming one word per line) is as follows:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    keywords = f.readlines()
```

The rest of your code may actually work better than you expect. I'm not able to test it right now (and don't have your spreadsheet to try it on anyway), but if you're relying on nfound to give you an accurate count for all keywords, you've made a small but significant mistake: it's set to zero *inside* the loop, and thus you only get a count for the last keyword. Move nfound = 0 outside the loop.

In Python, the way to iterate over lists - or just about anything - is not to increment an integer and then use that integer to index the value in the list. Rather loop over the list (or other iterable) itself:

```
for keyword in keywordlist:
    ...
```

As a hint, you shouldn't need nkeywords at all.

I hope this gets you on the right track. When asking questions in future, it'd be a great help to provide more information about what goes wrong, and preferably enough to be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you! I underestimated the importance of keeping a code as simple as possible, if only to be able to spot errors more easily. I now see what I did wrong (forgetting to lower the case of the cellcontent for comparison). I'll also work your suggestions into my code, for practice!